# Do linear properties of inner product apply to variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

If there was an inner product between two vectors, say:

$\langle x , a \rangle$

with $x$ being a variable and $a$ a constant. Would the following equality be valid?

$\langle x , a \rangle  b = \langle xb,a\rangle = x\langle b,a \rangle$

Assuming linear properties, I would think this is correct, but I'm not sure with $x$ being variable.

Comment: Mathematically, there is very little difference between variables and constants. That difference is only relevant when you're done calculating and it's time to interpret your result.

Comment: Well, of course $\;x\;$ **must** be a vector, which you call "variable" just because you want to. From a formal point of view, we don't care what **you** call your symbols, yet they must be things which belong to the correct set or linear space or whatever. An inner product on a linear space $\;V\;$ over a field $\;F\;$ is a function $\;V\times V\to F\;$ , so both its arguments must be in $\;V\;$ ...

Comment: What does $xb$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner product is defined like this
$$
\langle ., . \rangle : V \times V \to F
$$
for some vector space $V$ over some field $F$, two vectors from $V$ get a scalar from $F$ assigned.

**Regarding your first equation:**
$$
\langle x , a \rangle  b = \langle xb,a\rangle
$$

A general inner product over complex numbers is
$$
\langle x, y \rangle = y^+ M x
$$
where $+$ is adjugation (not sure if this a correct English term), thus transposition and complex conjugation, and $M$ is some Hermitian positive-definite matrix, typically the identity matrix.

So
$$
\langle x , a \rangle  b = (a^+ M x) b = a^+ M (xb) = \langle xb,a\rangle
$$
So your equality is true, where $x, a$ should be vectors from $V$, $b$ a scalar from $F$.

**Regarding your second equation:**

The second equation 
$$
\langle xb,a\rangle = x\langle b,a \rangle
$$
is only true if $V = F$, otherwise $\langle b,a \rangle$ makes no sense.